# Access static method from another class

Tags: java, compilation

I am trying to access a `static` method from another class, like:

```
package mersennepackage;

public class A {
    public static void foo() { ... }
}
```

and

```
import java.primespackage.mersennepackage.*;

public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.foo();
    }
}
```

I have compiled `A.java` and the class file is on my desktop at:
`/Users/usr/Desktop/primespackage/mersennepackage`.

Now, how do I use `A.java` from `B.java`? Can someone tell me the **compilation and execution commands**? I work on a MacOsx platform.

---

My complete code is class `MersennePrime` as `A`:

```
package mersennepackage;

public class MersennePrime {
    public static boolean checkForMersenneprime(int n) {
        int i;
        double d;
        d = Math.log(n + 1) / Math.log(2);
        i = (int)(Math.floor(d));
        if (d - i == 0)
            return true;
        return false;
      }
}
```

and class `TwinPrimes` as `B`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.primespackage.mersennepackage.*;

class TwinPrimes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        System.out.println(MersennePrime.checkForMersenneprime(sc.nextInt()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use an IDE. Not compiling Java from random text files on the Desktop

Comment: @usr123: You said `PrimeMain`, but I just see `TwinPrimes` class. There is a little mistake there.

Comment: I don't see how your question is related to all that prime stuff. Your question basically is just *"How to call a method from another class"*. You could simply remove all the non-relevant stuff from your question and show an example with 3 lines: `public class A { public static void foo() { ... } }` and `public class B { public static void main(String[] args) { B.foo(); } }`.

Comment: Feel free to revert my edit if you think that I am missing your point completely.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the errors!!Its working now.

Answer (score 2):

first you need to edit package name in MersennePrime class to primespackage.mersennepackage

```
package primespackage.mersennepackage;

public class MersennePrime{
    public static boolean checkForMersenneprime(int n){
         int i;
         double d;
         d=Math.log(n+1)/Math.log(2);
         i=(int)(Math.floor(d));
         if(d-i==0)
         return true;
         return false;
   }
}
```

and fix import statement like this

```
import java.util.*;
import primespackage.mersennepackage.*;

public class TwinPrimes{
     public static void main(String[] args){
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter the number");
         System.out.println(MersennePrime
               .checkForMersenneprime(sc.nextInt()));
    }
}
```

than zip the primespackage folder/dirctory
and rename the primespackage.zip to primespackage.jar
next use flowing commend to compile:

```
javac -cp "primespackage.jar" TwinPrimes.java
```

> -cp is used to jar files to class path

and this commend to run :

```
java -cp "primespackage.jar" TwinPrimes
```